# How to retrieve data form table by choosing one row from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two table like this

[image]

I want write SQL query that retrieve FORD,MAZDA,TOYOTA when the owner is John
and another SQL query to retrieve MITSUBISHI , JEEP , HONDA when the owner is Joseph.

Can I do that ?

Can you help me?

Comment: There is no relation between these two tables.

Comment: make relation using foreign key.

Comment: You either need a foreign relationship on cars pointing to owner for one to many, or an intermediate table to set up a many to many relationship

Comment: create foreign key for relation. create id for every user and out it into car table.

Comment: A little bit of [googling](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+create+relationship+between+two+tables+in+mysql) even reveals a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZCq219xiDc) on what relations are and how to set them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute and import these tables into your database in phpmyadmin

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 15, 2016 at 02:06 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.17
-- PHP Version: 5.5.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `testing`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cars`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` text NOT NULL,
  `car` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cars`
--

INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `owner_id`, `car`) VALUES
(1, '1255', 'FORD'),
(2, '1255', 'MAZDA'),
(3, '1255', 'TOYOTA'),
(4, '1455', 'MITSUBISHI'),
(5, '1455', 'JEEP'),
(6, '1455', 'HONDA');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `owners`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owners` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` text NOT NULL,
  `owner` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `owners`
--

INSERT INTO `owners` (`id`, `owner_id`, `owner`) VALUES
(1, '1255', 'Jhon'),
(2, '1455', 'Joseph');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

and then execute this query below

```
SELECT cars.*
FROM cars
JOIN owners
ON owners.owner_id = cars.owner_id
where cars.owner_id ='1455'
Order By cars.car ASC
```

now you will understand the basic way to do what you asked

Answer (score 0):

This is a many to many relation
take a look at this:
http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a pivot table to connect those two entity types together.
But first you need a primary key for each table.

```
companies
---------
id   PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE

owners
------
id   PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

Now the pivot

```
companies_owners
----------------
company INT NOT NULL REFERENCES companies
owner   INT NOT NULL REFERENCES owners
```

The pivot should also have a unique index on `company`,`owner`